Thieving couple live in mountain cave; man sprayed by liquid gold in the end
Thieving couple live in the mountain cave and in the end of the movie the man got sprayed by liquid gold they stole and became a statue. May be 80's-90's movies (could be older) but one of those movies that use high tech. One of the scene was the couple having sex in the bed filled with gold and dollars.
The male thief was the main character in the movie and when he became a statue, he didn't die; his eyes were moving and winked at the wife (the actress) at the very last scene. He was wearing a mask maybe, one of his hands was covering up his head.

I wonder if you mean Hudson Hawk with Bruce Willis from 1991. There's a couple of thieves living in a castle on a mountain and one of them suffers the fate you've described in the end.

thank for ur help but not quite, the thief man was the main character in the movie and when he become a statue, he didn't die his eyes were moving and winked at the wife (the actress)(at the very ending scene). he was wearing a mask may be, one of his hand was covering up to his head. may be it's older movie than i thought.

Thanks. The extra details helped and I have a better match in mind.

Probably Danger: Diabolik from 1968. From IMDb:

In psychedelic swinging 60s style, the dreaded thief (and killer) Diabolik wreaks havoc on a generic European country for his own financial gain and amusement. He shares an extravagant underground lair (and a giant bed of money) with his curvaceous, superficial girlfriend...

Diabolik steals a load of gold, but in the end:

The steel casket containing the gold had been irradiated, which allows the police to trace it. They close in on Diabolik who is melting the gold, to put it into ingots. Being shot at by the police, Diabolik is unable to control the heating of the gold which leads to Diabolik and the cavern being covered in molten gold. Again, Diabolik is believed to be dead, with his heat-proof suit now covered in hardened gold. The police seal off the place to later recover it. Eva is allowed to pay her respects to the dead Diabolik, who winks at her.

Here's the trailer, where you can see the couple in a bed full of money around 0:30:




YESSSSSS, that's. thank you.
